# Unable to change file and folder owner and permission from root to other users ( Ubunto 20.4)

Tags: permissions, root, chmod, chown

I am new to linux. I have a partition in which all the folder and files  owner is set as root.I am unable to change anything using chomd and chown when i write the commands as : **sudo chown -c -v user testfile.txt.**
The output is : *change ownership from root to user.*
But when i do **ls -l** my file have user and group permission still set to root.
Permission and owner changes successfully in my Desktop files and directories.
Its just problem in one partition.
I am very thankful if anyone help me in this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is failing on a partition if that partition is formatted using a file system that does not support linux file permissions. The file systems of Microsoft, i.e. fat, vfat, extfat and ntfs do not support linux permissions. Permissions for the entire drive are set during mounting.

With the utility "Disks", you can "take ownership" of an entire partition, including partitions formatted with a file system that does not support Linux permissions.

- Open Disks
- In the left pane, click the drive where the partition resides
- On the map on the right pane, click the partition you want to change
- Click the cog wheel icon and select "Take Ownership"

Comment: Thank for guiding me. Yes i have my file system set to NTFS/exFAT/HPFS (Bootable) i think this is causing the problem. But when i click the cog icon there is no option of "Take Ownership" two of the option there present are : 1 ) Edit file system 2) Edit partition . The edit partition option open empty check box and Edit file system option opens a list in which my file system set to NTFS in window section. There are four options in linux section as well Linux Swap, linux, linux raid, linux Lvm. Did i have to select from one of these? is it fix my problem? Did my data will loss or not?

Comment: No, do not edit, it'll break. Are you dual-booting with Windows? If so you must disable Windows' Fast Startup feature. If not then you shouldn't keep NTFS partitions because when (not if) they need error correction that can be done only with Windows tools.

Comment: Now i have NTFS partition system and if i remove dual boot  now. how i convert my partition from window to linux files systems?

Comment: You can use "Disks" also to reformat a partition, e.g. to another file system format.